# Deploying a Laravel app built with LaraDock to Heroku

Tags: laravel, docker, heroku, laradock

I have a `heroku.yml` file created in the root directory of my application. According to the Heroku documentation, I should point `build.docker.web` to some specific Dockerfile (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml). However, my app (built with LaraDock) references multiple Dockerfiles and I'm not sure which one specifically I'm supposed to point `build.docker.web` to in order to successfully build my app on Heroku.

I run my dev environment with `docker-compose` using `docker-compose up -d nginx redis postgres` to get my LaraDock containers up and running:

- laradock_redis
- laradock_nginx
- laradock_postgres
- laradock_php-fpm
- laradock_workspace
- docker:dind

I understand from Heroku docs that I should not include Postgres or Redis images in my build, as I'll be using Heroku add-ons for those. However, how do I include all the other containers in my `heroku.yml`? Do I need to include all of them? Which of these container's Dockerfile do I need to point `build.docker.web` to? I am totally clueless and there is near-literally a negative-space of information on how to deploy LaraDock to Heroku.

Any guidance or if you have an example `heroku.yml` you've set up for LaraDock that you could share would be much appreciated!

I've read over the Heroku documentation several times on how to deploy dockerized apps, but I guess it's just a bit too complex and convoluted to me at this point on how to utilize this with something like LaraDock.

Please dont point me to the Heroku articles around this. I've read them 8 ways to Sunday with no luck understanding what I should be doing.

I understand how I would deploy if I had a single Dockerfile sitting in the root of my project, but I don't. I have a `laradock` subdirectory that contains my images with their respective Dockerfiles and then I spin that up using a `docker-compose.yml` file sitting in that same `laradock` subdir for dev. How do I translate this over to a deployment for Heroku?

UPDATE: I ended up making some progress here on my own, but I don't have time to squash a bug, create a bug, squash a bug, etc until I understand this fully. I've switched back to using a Procfile for Heroku for the time being.